# Using ASP.NET readonly session with SignalR websockets

Tags: asp.net, signalr

I am trying to use a readonly ASP.NET session as shown by David Fowler in this gist: https://gist.github.com/davidfowl/4692934

But does this also apply when using WebSockets as the transport> I am running IIS (Express) 8.0.
What I see is that the hub method is called before the Application_BeginRequest method is called or Application_BeginRequest is not called at all. (I am using SignalR version 1.1.0)
Which Application events are called when a SignalR request is received?

Answer (score 1):

Begin request should be called once during the websocket handshake and never called again after that. Hub invocations do not imply an http request is being made.

Comment: ok, clear. And that HttpContext which is available during the handshake will remain available as long as the connection is alive? So it is available in Hub invocations?
My concrete issue is that I have culture information available in the sessionstate and I want to use that to set the current culture of the thread on which the hub invocation is executed.

Comment: Can't get it to work. In the Application_BeginRequest I have Context.SetSessionStateBehavior(System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateBehavior.ReadOnly); but in the Hub Context.Request.GetHttpContext().Session is still null.